# google maps: getSelected marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set up a little program with google maps and markers. I have been trying for a while to fire the click event on a marker which is selected but I was not succesful. 
My idea what I want to achieve: On a google Map I can set several Markers(That works!). Then, if I click on of the markers which I have set I would like to get the click event for the specific clicked marker, and I am not able to get this.

I only get the click event on the first marker which is set, but not on the ones which I click manually on the map. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
// Check to see if the browser supports the GeoLocation API.
if (navigator.geolocation) {

var markers = [];

// Get the location
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon = position.coords.longitude;
showMap(lat, lon);
});


} else {
  // Print out a message to the user.
  document.write('Your browser does not support GeoLocation');
}


// Show the user's position on a Google map.
function showMap(lat, lon) {
// Create a LatLng object with the GPS coordinates.
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

// Create the Map Options
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// Generate the Map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
// Add a Marker to the Map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  draggable:true,
  title: 'Found you!'
});


  map.addListener( 'click', function(e) {
      console.log("ASD");
   var latitude = e.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = e.latLng.lng();
    console.log( latitude + ', ' + longitude );
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          console.log("i : " + i + " " + marker.getPosition());
        }
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });

  function placeMarker(position, map) {
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });  
    console.log("M POS " + marker.getPosition());
    markers.push(marker);
  console.log("QQQQ  " + marker.getPosition());
    //map.panTo(position);
  }

        map.addListener( 'rightclick', function(e) {
            console.log("SSSS");
    clearMarkers();
  });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log("MARKER!!");
                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"Hello World!"
    });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });



  }

  function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
      }

  function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the onclick event for only the first marker you put on the map when you geolocate the user's location. This is why the infowindow only shows up for the first marker. I have modified your code and put the same logic for the click event in the placeMarker function. I believe that it now has the behavior you desire. I'll show you my code addition to the function:

```
function placeMarker(position, map) {
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {                                  
    console.log("MARKER!!");                                              
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({                
        content:"Hello World!"                                                  
    });                                                                       
        infowindow.open(map,marker);                                                
    });                                                                   

console.log("M POS " + marker.getPosition());
markers.push(marker);
console.log("QQQQ  " + marker.getPosition());
//map.panTo(position);
}
```

I also have a JSFiddle to demonstrate this, please note that I redacted my API key for security, so you will need to input your own for this sample to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/kxxhvzL0/

I hope this helps!